# How to use the disruptor library as an object pool only?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I am currently optimizing code that reloads a huge amount of data from the database periodically. Every time this operation is executed ~800k objects are created and released to be garbage collected as soon as the operation is over.

As one optimization of the code, I'd like to use an object pool in order to re-use the objects in the pool and lower impact on garbage collection a bit. I thought about using the disruptor library for this purpose but regretfully I could not find any recent example dealing with borrowing and giving back objects to the pool. The most examples are focused on message handling.

My question now would be, if there is any example project/code out there dealing with the pooling only or if somebody could provide the ideas how to tackle this with disruptor.

**UPDATE**
I found [this](https://github.com/dclusin/objPool) github repo which basically implements a pooling solution using disruptor in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Object Pooling Concept is used in the place where you can borrow the  object (i.e calling borrow()) and you should return the object  (i.e calling returnObject() method ) to the pool
else the object pooling will fail.
If you can able to return the object again to pool once the object is not needed,then try it out. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully is sure that it is really disruptor what you need. In a very simplified way

> disruptor is a way to have producers and consumers communicate
>   lock-free and with efficient memory handling.

A more details answer ([here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/244831)) gives you a full explanation on the inner workings of a disruptor implementation.

What you seem to be doing based on this problem statement:

*... optimizing code that reloads a huge amount of data from
 the database periodically. Every time this operation is executed ~800k
 objects are created and released to be garbage collected ...*

**For this purpose I would only use a simple caching mechanism.** If you load your data once, then constantly provide access to it for your processes each time they need it, your GC load will be as optimized as it gets. Regarding other concerns:

- data staleness
- memory consumption
- parallel read and write
- etc.

proper caching parametrization can be used to address them (evictation, read-ahead refresh, read-through behavior, etc.).

Comment: The problem is, that the stated objects are currently only used as temporary objects and immediately transferred to some different representation. The later ones are cached until the next reload happens. The whole situation is not ideal, I agree, but due to several reason, I cannot change the general handling now but only take care about the temporary objects.

Answer (score 0):

The disruptor behaves like a queue. Items must move along in order.

An ordinary pool couldn't ensure that items are freed in the same order there were obtained. This means a lot of clogging would occur, victim of the longest time an item is used.

If you have N threads working, you need no more than N items to work. That's a nice place for a threadlocal, or even allocate on thread stack (local variable) outside the loop (pass in argument if necessary).

Now, your case it different a bit. You already know they come from one place, a database result set I guess. Why not stream the rows to pool of N handlers? You may never need to allocate more than N items to load the row and perform work.

If items are local variables, chances are the jit will allocate on the thread stack, not in heap, and the gc tax will be escaped.

Anyway, streaming is better than filling 800'000 instances and delaying processing. And when they are short lived (as in streaming), the GC tax is minimal since they are all in the young generation.